# Windows Server 2008 Firewall - Allow RDP (3389) only from specific IPs

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

I have a Windows Server 2008 which I would like to access via RDP on port 3389. I make a forwarding on my router, but I would like to allow only my IP to access the port 3389 on the Windows Server.

Is this something that is doable? Maybe with the Windows Firewall?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the windows firewall rule, click on the "scope" tab.

Under "Remote IP Address" click "These IP Addresses".

Add your IP to the list and click OK.

From the on, only connections originating from the IPs you specify here will be able to connect.